# Unable to install ad-hoc watchOS companion app

Tags: ios, react-native, watchos

I have a companion app for my react-native iOS app. I created an ad-hoc build to install it. But the install just fails when I try to install it to the watch. I couldn't find anything useful from the watch logs.
Here are the logs from the phone:

> default   01:20:50.611742+0530    Bridge  -[COSApplicationLinkCell installApp]
> default 01:20:50.611900+0530    Bridge  Check if app  needs update for 
> default 01:20:50.613363+0530    atc request keybag sync to paired device
> default 01:20:50.613459+0530    atc |initiating keybag re-sync with priority 0
> default 01:20:50.614612+0530    appconduitd 0x16ff8b000 -[ACXDeviceConnectionClient installApplication:withProvisioningProfileInfo:forTestFlight:onDeviceWithPairingID:completion:]: Requested by Bridge (pid 511) for app fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch not for test flight
> default 01:20:50.615236+0530    appconduitd 0x16ff8b000 -[ACXGizmoAppState setInstallStatus:]: Created unique install ID for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch : fa48d8ed2f36c124829fe7b4d17caa7a
> default 01:20:50.615386+0530    appconduitd key: (AppStateVersion); value type: (CFNumberRef): value: (2); completionHandler: (0x0)
> default 01:20:50.615664+0530    appconduitd requesting keybag sync to paired device
> default 01:20:50.615812+0530    appconduitd key: (CompletedInitialPairedSync); value type: (CFBooleanRef): value: (1); completionHandler: (0x0)
> default 01:20:50.616108+0530    appconduitd key: (ApplicationStates); value type: (CFDictionaryRef): value: (); completionHandler: (0x0)
> default 01:20:50.616367+0530    appconduitd key: (NeedsReunionSync); value type: (CFBooleanRef): value: (0); completionHandler: (0x0)
> default 01:20:50.617265+0530    appconduitd key: (PendingAppUpdateStates); value type: (CFArrayRef): value: (); completionHandler: (0x0)
> default 01:20:50.617424+0530    appconduitd
> default 01:20:50.617501+0530    filecoordinationd   Received claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41
> default 01:20:50.617578+0530    appconduitd Write options: 0 -- URL:  -- purposeID: 070EF6EA-3D01-4DC3-935D-CDC8F7BAF0CA -- claimID: 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41
> default 01:20:50.618812+0530    filecoordinationd   Claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 granted in server
> default 01:20:50.619359+0530    filecoordinationd   Claimer for 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 is waiting for presenter 070EF6EA-3D01-4DC3-935D-CDC8F7BAF0CA on the same item to relinquish
> default 01:20:50.619671+0530    filecoordinationd   Presenter 070EF6EA-3D01-4DC3-935D-CDC8F7BAF0CA has finished relinquishing, unblocking claimer for 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41
> default 01:20:50.619781+0530    filecoordinationd   Claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 invoked in server
> default 01:20:50.620120+0530    Bridge  App () does not require update.
> default 01:20:50.620379+0530    Bridge  -[COSApplicationLinkCell installNanoBundle:forDevice:]
> default 01:20:50.620786+0530    appconduitd Claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 granted in client
> default 01:20:50.620879+0530    appconduitd Claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 invoked in client
> default 01:20:50.620953+0530    appconduitd self: (0x206750648); domainDict: (); url: ()
> default 01:20:50.621665+0530    atc <ATDeviceMessageLink: 0x125df1b30, type=1, open=1> ---> [ID=14, BeginKeybagSync Request, AirFair2, params=[0 bytes], payload=[0 bytes], EOF=1]
> default 01:20:50.634351+0530    appconduitd domain: (); queue: ((null)); pairingID: (); pairingDataStore: ()
> default 01:20:50.634490+0530    appconduitd self: (0x10038a180); queue: ((null)); internalAccessor: (0x10035f7c0)
> default 01:20:50.634546+0530    appconduitd
> default 01:20:50.634598+0530    appconduitd self: (0x10038a180)
> default 01:20:50.634964+0530    appconduitd 0x170017000 -[ACXInstallQueue installWatchApp:withPriority:appSettings:provisioningProfileInfo:isUserInitiated:completion:]_block_invoke: Enqueueing (first) install operation for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch
> default 01:20:50.635272+0530    filecoordinationd   Claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41 was revoked
> default 01:20:50.635332+0530    filecoordinationd   Making presenter 070EF6EA-3D01-4DC3-935D-CDC8F7BAF0CA reacquire after claim 821CB7C0-4A82-4B1C-9B83-F18B46143C41
> default 01:20:50.635620+0530    appconduitd 0x170017000 -[ACXInstallQueue _onQueue_deQueueNextOperation]: Dequeued install operation for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch (0 remaining in queue)
> default 01:20:50.637666+0530    installd    0x16d243000 -[MIClientConnection snapshotWKAppInCompanionAppID:toURL:options:completion:]: Snapshot requested for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta by appconduitd (pid 134) to /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.AppConduit.staging/fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch_cTxswK/Transfer with options {
> CreatePlaceholderOption = 1;
> }
> default 01:20:50.639719+0530    com.apple.MobileInstallationHelperService   0x16f7d7000 -[MobileInstallationHelperService createAppSnapshotWithBundleID:snapshotToURL:onlyV1AppIfPresent:placeholderOnly:completion:]: Snapshot requested for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta to /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.AppConduit.staging/fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch_cTxswK/Transfer. V1: 0, placeholder: 1
> default 01:20:50.642383+0530    containermanagerd   command=, client=, error=
> default 01:20:50.643722+0530    containermanagerd   command=, client=, error=
> default 01:20:50.645194+0530    containermanagerd   command=, client=, error=
> default 01:20:50.646353+0530    containermanagerd   command=, client=, error=
> default 01:20:50.711675+0530    appconduitd 0x16ff8b000 -[ACXServerInstallOperation _onQueue_prepForTransferAndInstall]: Acquiring socket for fit.cure.intl.ios.beta.watch (p = Y, ui = Y)
> default 01:20:50.711987+0530    appconduitd 0x170017000 -[ACXIDSSocketManager _onInternalQueue_initiateConnectionWithCompletionBlock:]: Starting socket setup for stream ID 45562B9B-CA58-42AC-B54A-9A109EAF4DBE
> default 01:20:50.714184+0530    appconduitd 0x170017000 -[ACXIDSSocketManager _sendMessage:messageDictionary:withAcknowledgement:error:]: Sent socket setup message with IDS ID 2E98F311-4606-4F9B-A183-1777E188267A
> default 01:21:01.748374+0530    Bridge  installApplication  error: (Error Domain=ACXErrorDomain Code=17 UserInfo={SourceFileLine=633, NSLocalizedDescription=, FunctionName=})

Can anyone help me make sense of this log? What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be watch UDID not included in the provisioning profile. ‍♂️